# Slow data.frame filling

Tags: performance, r, dataframe, apply

I have `length(Date_List)` number of days for which I have info on `length(ISIN_Table$ID)` items.
For each Day (loop in j) I create a dataframe of zeroes that can hold all items (`length(ISIN_Table$ID)`), and some columns (4).

Each item will be a row in every matrix, but depending on the date will have different filling.

```
#create list that will hold matrices
df.list<-vector("list", length(Dates_List))
for (j in 1:(length(Dates_List))){
  df.list[[j]] <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = length(ISIN_Table$ID),ncol=4))
}

#Loop over number of days
for (j in 1:(length(Dates_List))){
  date<-Dates_List[j]
  #create empty dataframe 
  df.list[[j]] <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=length(ISIN_Table$ID), ncol=4))

  #loop over every item
  for (i in 1:(length(ISIN_Table$ID))){
    #check whether item is known at date
    if (nrow(data.raw[data.raw$ID==i & data.raw$Date==date,]) < 1){
      ID<-i
      df.list[[j]][i,1]<-date
      df.list[[j]][i,2]<-ID     #fill up the row
    }
    else{
      #fill up the row
      df.list[[j]][i,]<-c(
        as.character(data.raw[data.raw$ID==i & data.raw$Date==date,"Date"]),
        (data.raw[data.raw$ID==i & data.raw$Date==date,"ID"]),
        (data.raw[data.raw$ID==i & data.raw$Date==date,"Bid.Price"]),
        (data.raw[data.raw$ID==i & data.raw$Date==date,"Ask.Price"]))
    }
  }
}
```

The code gives me the exact output I want, it it incredibly slow however. I would appreciate any comments on how to improve speed, current version is not workable.

## UPDATE:

```
# create dummy data:

Dates_List<-c("2007-01-02", "2007-01-03")
ISIN_Table<-data.frame(c(1,2,3))
colnames(ISIN_Table)<-"ID"
ID<-rep(1:2, len=2, each=1)
Date<-c("2007-01-02","2007-01-02","2007-01-03", "2007-01-03")
Bid.Price<-rep(100,4)
Ask.Price<-rep(100,4)
data.raw<-data.frame(ID, Date, Bid.Price, Ask.Price)
```

Asking for df.list[[1]] returns:

```
          X1 X2  X3  X4
1 2007-01-02  1 100 100
2 2007-01-02  2 100 100
3 2007-01-02  3   0   0
```

Comment: for loops in R are slow. you can try `apply` family functions. Also without reproducible data, it's hard to answer such a question.

Comment: looks like you are just trying to split the data.raw by dates and if you don't have any particular `ID` for any particular date you are populating it with 0

Comment: `for` loops are not slow. Creating and subsetting data.frames is slow.

Comment: @Roland I meant there are much better way of getting work done in R than using for loops :)

Comment: @Smackboyg, it is better if you edit your question to explain your problem (rather than asking to fix your code), by providing *sample data* (what is `data.raw` for example?) and showing us the output you require. You'll get better solutions. As such the question is not constructive (or too localised) and if it remains so, after a while, I'll vote to close.

Comment: @geektrader, I am checking whether particular ID has data on particular date. If so populate with full data, if not populate with 0 basically.

Comment: @Roland, aside from the loops assign this df.list[[j]][i,]<- is the slow part of the function. Any suggestions for subsetting?

Comment: I am confident that there is a vectorized solution. Give us sample data to work with and we can show you how to do this without loops.

Comment: @Roland I have added sample data and the output it produces. I hope this helps

Comment: @Smackboyg, you would like to split the data.frame to have 3 items per `date`, is it?

Comment: @Arun, I split the data.frame by date and have length(ISIN$ID) times, in this case 3, correct

Comment: I suspect that you got stuck at a step in your workflow, which you probably could avoid altogether. It is still not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but I have even more problems to think of a reason why you would need this.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** 
As per @Arun's suggestion, you can add missing rows before splitting and avoid mapply altogether

```
Dates_List <- c("2007-01-02", "2007-01-03")
ISIN_Table <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3))
colnames(ISIN_Table) <- "ID"
ID <- rep(1:2, len = 2, each = 1)
Date <- c("2007-01-02", "2007-01-02", "2007-01-03", "2007-01-03")
Bid.Price <- rep(100, 4)
Ask.Price <- rep(100, 4)
data.raw <- data.frame(ID, Date, Bid.Price, Ask.Price)

temp <- expand.grid(Dates_List, ISIN_Table$ID)
names(temp) <- c("Date", "ID")

data.raw <- merge(temp, data.raw, all.x = TRUE)
data.raw[is.na(data.raw)] <- 0
data.raw
##         Date ID Bid.Price Ask.Price
## 1 2007-01-02  1       100       100
## 2 2007-01-02  2       100       100
## 3 2007-01-02  3         0         0
## 4 2007-01-03  1       100       100
## 5 2007-01-03  2       100       100
## 6 2007-01-03  3         0         0


splitdata <- split(data.raw, data.raw$Date)

splitdata
## $`2007-01-02`
##         Date ID Bid.Price Ask.Price
## 1 2007-01-02  1       100       100
## 2 2007-01-02  2       100       100
## 3 2007-01-02  3         0         0
## 
## $`2007-01-03`
##         Date ID Bid.Price Ask.Price
## 4 2007-01-03  1       100       100
## 5 2007-01-03  2       100       100
## 6 2007-01-03  3         0         0
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You can use `split` to split data by dates and then nifty use of `mapply` and `merge` to get row for even the IDs which doesn't have any data on given date.

```
Dates_List <- c("2007-01-02", "2007-01-03")
ISIN_Table <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3))
colnames(ISIN_Table) <- "ID"
ID <- rep(1:2, len = 2, each = 1)
Date <- c("2007-01-02", "2007-01-02", "2007-01-03", "2007-01-03")
Bid.Price <- rep(100, 4)
Ask.Price <- rep(100, 4)
data.raw <- data.frame(ID, Date, Bid.Price, Ask.Price)

splitdata <- split(data.raw, data.raw$Date)

mapply(FUN = function(x, date) merge(x, 
                          data.frame(ID = ISIN_Table$ID, 
                                     Date = rep(date, length(ISIN_Table$ID))), 
                                 all.y = TRUE), 
       splitdata, t(names(splitdata)), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

## $`2007-01-02`
##   ID       Date Bid.Price Ask.Price
## 1  1 2007-01-02       100       100
## 2  2 2007-01-02       100       100
## 3  3 2007-01-02        NA        NA
## 
## $`2007-01-03`
##   ID       Date Bid.Price Ask.Price
## 1  1 2007-01-03       100       100
## 2  2 2007-01-03       100       100
## 3  3 2007-01-03        NA        NA
```

Comment: (+1) Very nice use of `expand.grid` and `merge`!